# Where can I learn more of either pass in a Context (so you can access resources), or make the helper methods static?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-context, android-toast

I need to use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext())`. The `getApplicationContext()` is what I am really after. I need a specific tutorial on passing `Context` around. Any sugestions? I see alot of developers answering questions with techo-speak like this and I would seriously like to advance to that stage. I have run into passing `Context` issues way too often and would like a deep understanding of this. Until I get this type of knowledge I will always consider myself a noob.
Thanks.

Comment: there aren't a lot of concepts that you should know about Context. The number one thing, IMO, that you should be aware while passing Context around is memory leaks caused by keeping a long-lived references to a Context. I guess this comes with practice. But here's a good start to Context and memory leaks: http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a problem with `Activity` being a `Context` ? (`Activity.this`)??

Android already does that for you so why do you want to bother your head.? When you create a `View` the Context is passed to the View eg; `TextView textv = new TextView(Context);` you can later retrieve that `Context` with `View.getContext()`. Honestly `Context` are everywhere so why do you really want to use the `getApplicationContext();` why not `getBaseContext()`

Comment: I think from bits and bytes to systems integration. The incessant need to understand under the hood is compulsive with me. Other people had to create it and I want to know it. There are some really deep answers I have seen and I would like to know the concept to syntax relationship instead of copying and pasting then hammering away at debugging to get things to work.